# How to get rid of linking error in mfc?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2013, mfc, linker

During the proccess of linking the LNK2001 error happens:

- LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual struct CRuntimeClass * __thiscall CChildView::GetRuntimeClass(void)const " (?GetRuntimeClass@CChildView@@UBEPAUCRuntimeClass@@XZ)

Why would this be?

Here is the relevant code in the header:

```
class CChildView :public CDialog
{

    DECLARE_DYNAMIC(CChildView)

public:

    CChildView();
    ~CChildView();
    afx_msg void OnPaint();
    afx_msg void OnLevelProf();
    afx_msg void OnLevelAmat();
    afx_msg void OnLevelBeg();
    afx_msg void OnStepC();
    void new_game();
    //void CloseWindow();
    BOOL PreCreateWindow(CREATESTRUCT& cs);
    int end_analyze();
    void ii();
    unsigned long calculate(int id, int x, int y);
    afx_msg void OnNewGame();
    //void Invalidate();
    afx_msg void OnX1010();
    afx_msg void OnX1919();
    afx_msg void OnX3030();
    afx_msg void OnX5050();
    afx_msg void OnX100100();
    //MessageBoxW();
    void resize_window();
    afx_msg void OnLButtonDown(UINT, CPoint xy);
    //void GetWindowRect(RECT);
    //int MessageBoxW();
     void OnStepH();
    void set_chеcked_menu(unsigned int old_id, unsigned int new_id);
    DECLARE_MESSAGE_MAP()
};
```

And the part of .cpp file:

```
//IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CChildView, CWnd)//!without this - doesn`t compiles. With - //runtime failure
BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP(CChildView, CWnd)
    ON_WM_PAINT()
    ON_WM_LBUTTONDOWN()
    .....
    END_MESSAGE_MAP()
```

But during the execution of my programm (if implement_dynamicaly is uncommented) it fails in AfxWinMain function on the line:

```
if (!pThread->InitInstance())
```

My other classes don't explicitly define them and they don't have errors. 
Here is somethink like this, but it didn`t help me. 
[MFC dlg class link errors for MyClass::GetMessageMap() and MyClass::GetRuntimeClass (MSVC 2008)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5150056/mfc-dlg-class-link-errors-for-myclassgetmessagemap-and-myclassgetruntimecl)

Comment: Since you're using `DECLARE_DYNAMIC` you need the `IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC`. Your question is not about linking. It is about run-time behavior of your program, and you have provided next to no information about that. Fire up your debugger. Find out what's going on.

Comment: You are driving from `CDialog`. But then you switch to `CWnd` in `IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC` and in `BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP`. From the look of your declarations I don't know if that's meant to be `CDialog` or `CWnd` or `CView`. For the time being comment out `DECLARE_DYNAMIC`. Also you should explain roughly what sort of view model you are after (dialog or multi-document view or single-document...)

Answer (score 4):

You commented out the line IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC(CChildView, CWnd).

You need to either comment out the DECLARE_DYNAMIC() macro in your CChildView class, or uncomment out the IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC--they have to do with the CRuntimeClass for your class.  Also, if you uncomment out the IMPLEMENT_DYNAMIC, you should make sure the baseclass in the macro matches the class you are deriving from.  IOW, it should say CDialog and not CWnd.  Also, your BEGIN_MESSAGE_MAP() suffers from the same problem.